# If Lesbegue integral is zero, is the measure zero?

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space, and $f: X \to [0, \infty)$ be a measurable function w.r.t. the $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ (i.e. $f^{-1}([0,\infty)) \in \Sigma$) such that $f \ne 0$ (i.e. $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in X$).

Is the following true?

If $$\int_{A} f d\mu = 0$$ where $A \in \Sigma$, does it imply that $\mu(A) = 0$?

I know that the converse is true: if the measure of $\mu(A) = 0$, then the Lesbegue integral is zero, i.e.:

$$\int_{A} f d\mu = 0$$

I wonder if this is true: Lesbegue integral equal zero, implies measure of zero. If it's not true, what is a counterexample of this?

I read in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7307/concerning-sets-of-lebesgue-measure-zero), the same thing but with outer measures, but I quite don't understand it well.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by $f\neq 0$. Does it mean $f$ is not identically zero or never zero or non-zero almost everywhere?

Comment: Note that $\int_{[0,1]} 1_{[1,2]} d m = 0$.

Comment: @geetha290krm, $f \ne 0$, means is never zero. Sorry for not clarifying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the answering more complete.

If $f\neq0$ stands for $f(x)>0$ for every $x\in X$ then yes.

Define $A_n=\{x\in A\mid f(x)\geq\frac1n\}$. Then:$$0=\int_Afd\mu\geq\int_{A_n}fd\mu\geq\frac1n\mu(A_n)$$showing that $\mu(A_n)=0$ for every $n$.

This while $A_1\subseteq A_2\subseteq\cdots\subseteq A$ with $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$.

This allows the conclusion that $\mu(A)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_n)=0$.

Comment: I am sure this is a duplicate.

Comment: @geetha290krm You are right and I confess my sin and feel ashamed. Also I (again) promise that in the future I will do more effort to avoid this situations. I have no real excuse but was too eager to answer. Unfortunately the answer is accepted which makes it impossible to delete it. If this changes (please OP...) then I will delete it (promise to you and others).

Comment: Never mind, it is just a slip, not a  sin!

Comment: @geetha290krm You eased my mind . Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

As copper.hat pointed out, $f$ can be non-zero on a set of positive measure, but the integral of $f$ over a set whose intersection with that set has measure zero may still be zero.

Another example is when $f$ is non-zero on a set of measure zero. Then $\int_A f\ \mathsf d\mu=0$ for any $A\in\Sigma$, no matter the value of $\mu(A)$. For example, if $f=\mathsf 1_{\mathbb Q}$, the indicator function of the rational numbers would satisfy $\int_{\mathbb R} f\ \mathsf d\mu =0$ where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure.

There are however nonnegative functions which are nowhere zero and satisfy your condition, see here: [Integral being zero implies measure of set is zero.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4072602/integral-being-zero-implies-measure-of-set-is-zero)