# If the integral of $f$ is $0$ then $f$ is $0$ almost everywhere

Tags: measure-theory

Claim:

If $f$ is a non-negative real valued function and $\int f d\mu = 0$ for a measure $\mu$, then $f$ is $0$ except on sets of $\mu$-measure $0$.

The proof I'm following goes:

Let $N_n = \mathbb 1 (f(x) \geq 1/n)$ so that $\mu N_n \leq n \mu f$ which is just $0$ by assumption. Then, taking the limit and applying monotone convergence, we have that $\mu\lim _nN_n=0$

My confusion comes from the first step. Why is $\mu N_n \leq n \mu f$?

Comment: Are you writing $\mu f$ to mean $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f\, d\mu$, and similarly $\mu N_n$ to mean $\int_{\mathbb{R}} N_n\, d\mu$? (or $\mathbb{R}^n$, etc)

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we defined the function $g(x) = \frac1{n} \cdot 1_{f(x) \geq 1/n}.$ For any given $x,$ if $f(x) \geq \frac1{n}$ then $g(x) = \frac{1}n,$ so $f(x) \geq g(x).$ Otherwise, if $0 \leq f(x) \leq \frac1{n}$ then $g(x) = 0,$ so again $f(x) \geq g(x).$

So, $f(x) \geq g(x)$ everywhere, and we can conclude that $\int f d\mu \geq \int g d\mu = \frac1{n} \int N_n d\mu.$ Does that clear it up?

Comment: This question has been answere many many times.In Fact, it was answered yesterday. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4612651/if-lesbegue-integral-is-zero-is-the-measure-zero/4612712?noredirect=1#comment9724502_4612712